# Help with Wikipedia's definition of an exterior algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors, exterior-algebra

The inforation in this question comes from two Wikipedia articles, namely, the articles [Tensor Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_algebra) and [Exterior Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra). I'll summarize all of the relevant information.

Let $V$ be an $F$-vector space. Then, if $k\geq 1$ define $T^k V$ to be the vector space of $k$-tensors on $V$, and define $T^0V = F$. Then the tensor algebra $T(V)$ on $V$ is defined as the direct sum of all $T^k V$ for $k\geq 0$, along with the tensor product.

Let $I$ be the ideal in $T(V)$ generated by all elements of $T(V)$ of the form $x\otimes x$ where $x\in V$. Then the exterior algebra on $V$ is defined as $\Lambda(V) = T(V)/I$.

I have two questions about the above.

First, it's my understanding that given two vector spaces $V$ and $W$, the direct sum $V\oplus W$ consists of elements of $V\times W$ along with the obvious vector space structure. The direct sum of vector spaces $V_1, V_2,...$ is given by the subset of $V_1\times V_2\times...$ consisting of elements with only finitely many nonzero components. However, intuitively, it is also my understanding that $T(V)$ should consist of tensors over $V$, but it appears that it consists of $\omega$-tuples of tensors over $V$ (with only finitely many nonzero). What should I make of this discrepancy?

Second, how can we take the tensor product of a vector $x\in V$ with itself in order to construct the ideal $I\subseteq T(V)$? It was my understanding that the tensor product would takes tensors as arguments, and I can't see any natural identification between elements of $V$ and certain elements of $T(V)$.

I apologize if I'm missing something obvious. Thanks in advance.

Comment: With regards to your second question, $T(V)=K\bigoplus V\bigoplus (V\bigotimes V)\bigoplus (V\bigotimes V\bigotimes V)...$ where $K$ is the scalar field of your vector space, $V$. So there is a natural copy of $V$ in $T(V)$.

Comment: @daruma Shouldn't the term after $K$ and before $T^2V = V\otimes V$ be $T^1V = V^*$, which is distinct from (and not naturally isomorphic to) $V$?

Comment: If that is the convention used in your textbook, I suppose then that is not true as the dual $V^*$ is only isomorphic to $V$ if it is a finite dimensional vector space(and the isomorphism is not canonical).

Comment: @florence No, $T^1(V)=V$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Evidently, I'm wrong about what a $1$-tensor is. As I understand, a $k$-tensor is a multilinear map from $V^k$ to $F$, and so a $1$-tensor is a multilinear map from $V$ to $F$. But if there's only one argument, then a multilinear map is the same as a linear map, and so a $1$-tensor is a linear map from $V$ to $F$, i.e. an element of $V^*$. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: @florence the elements of $T^k(V)$ are not "$k$-tensors" in your jargon. By definition, $T^k(V)$ is the $k$-fold iterated tensor product of the module $V$ with  itself. Your $k$-tensors are elements of the dual of $T^k(V)$.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense, so that takes care of the second question. Thank you!